# Django Unhandled exception in thread started by at python manage.py runserver

Tags: python, django

I am running Django project on linux(Ubuntu16.04), Recently i was uninstall my os and reinstall the same OS on my system.I have some django project previously it was working very well, after installing the os and All django packages It is not running but however if i create any new django  project with django-admin startproject name.. it works .

The following error i am getting

```js
Unhandled exception in thread started by <function check_errors.<locals>.wrapper at 0x7f7ceceb5730>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/balu/Desktop/yottaasys/django-hrms/hrm_env/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/utils/autoreload.py", line 227, in wrapper
    fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/balu/Desktop/yottaasys/django-hrms/hrm_env/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/runserver.py", line 117, in inner_run
    autoreload.raise_last_exception()
  File "/home/balu/Desktop/yottaasys/django-hrms/hrm_env/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/utils/autoreload.py", line 250, in raise_last_exception
    six.reraise(*_exception)
  File "/home/balu/Desktop/yottaasys/django-hrms/hrm_env/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/utils/six.py", line 685, in reraise
    raise value.with_traceback(tb)
  File "/home/balu/Desktop/yottaasys/django-hrms/hrm_env/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/utils/autoreload.py", line 227, in wrapper
    fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/balu/Desktop/yottaasys/django-hrms/hrm_env/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/__init__.py", line 22, in setup
    configure_logging(settings.LOGGING_CONFIG, settings.LOGGING)
  File "/home/balu/Desktop/yottaasys/django-hrms/hrm_env/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/utils/log.py", line 75, in configure_logging
    logging_config_func(logging_settings)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/logging/config.py", line 795, in dictConfig
    dictConfigClass(config).configure()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/logging/config.py", line 490, in configure
    raise ValueError("dictionary doesn't specify a version")
ValueError: dictionary doesn't specify a version
```

Answer (score 2):

you are missing 'version' from your logging settings.
https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/logging.config.html#dictionary-schema-details